# Project Euler #14: Program runs for long time

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve Project Euler #14:

```
The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive integers:

n → n/2 (n is even)
n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)  

Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following sequence:
               13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1  

Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
public class Problem14 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int longestLength = 1;
        int longestStart = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
            int candidate = getCollatzLength(i);
            if (candidate > longestLength) {
                longestLength = candidate;
                longestStart = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("starting point = " + longestStart);
    }

    public static int getCollatzLength(int startingNumber) {
        int length = 1;
        while (startingNumber != 1) {
            startingNumber = getNextCollatz(startingNumber);
            length++;
        }
        return length;
    }

    public static int getNextCollatz(int current) {
        if (current % 2 == 0) {
            return current / 2;
        } else {
            return 3 * current + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this runs for ages (more than 5 minutes).  Any idea what's going wrong here?

When I print the starting number that produces the current longest chain, the last one I get is:

```
new longest start is 106239
```

Comment: see this https://interviewquizandanswers.blogspot.com/2020/04/project-euler-14-longest-collatz.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it reaches 113,383, there are elements of the chain that go above 2^31-1 and thus out of the range of an `int`, and there are numerous other times that happens before you reach one million. The largest value it will hit in a chain is 56,991,483,520. If you change from `int` to `long` you should be okay.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of redundant calculations. For example, finding the length of the collatz sequence of 1,000,000 requires finding the collatz sequence of 500,000. You should store all of the intermediate results in an array/list to reduce redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://interviewquizandanswers.blogspot.com/2020/04/project-euler-14-longest-collatz.html)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();

        int result = 0;
        int maxcount = 0;

        int [] arr = new int[(int) (5 * Math.pow(10, 6) + 1)];
        for(int i=2;i<=3732423;i++) {
            int count = steps(i,0);
            if(count > maxcount) {
                result = i;
                maxcount = count;
            }
            else if(count == maxcount) {
                result = i;
            }
            arr[i] = result;
        }

        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            int no = in.nextInt();

            if(no > 3732423){
                System.out.println(3732423);
            }else{
                System.out.println(arr[no]);
            }
        }
    }


    public static int steps(long num,int count) {

        while(num !=1) {
            if(num % 2 == 0) {
                count++;
                num = num / 2;
            }
            else {
                count++;
                num = num*3 + 1;
            }
        }
        return count;

    }
}
```